# PHP split string for boolean search and create a mssql query

Tags: php, sql-server, boolean

I am trying to create a boolean search string in PHP to create a MSSQL WHERE clause.

I have the string that was entered into the search box:
Managing AND Director OR "Office Admin" NOT Global OR "IT Interim Managing"

I then clean the string and explode:

```
$searchText = preg_replace('/(&|\||-|!)(\S+)/imx', '$1 $2', $SampleSearch);
$keywords = explode(' ', $searchText);
```

I have played with a number of examples to create the Where clause but am really struggling. So far i have found the below but can not get it to create. I have tried a number of changes but still the same.

```
$newKeyWords = array();
            $string = '';
            $counter = 1;
            foreach( $keywords as $keyName){
                if( $keyName !== 'AND' && $keyName !== 'OR' && $keyName !== 'NOT'){
                    $string .= ' '.$keyName;
                    if( $counter == count($keywords) ){
                        $newKeyWords[] = trim($string);
                    }
                }else{
                    $newKeyWords[] = trim($string);
                    $newKeyWords[] = $keyName;
                    $string = '';
                }
                $counter++;
            }
```

I think the Where clause should look like the below once complete:

```
WHERE (((Position LIKE '%Managing%') AND (Position LIKE '%Director%')) OR ((Position LIKE '%Office Admin%'))) AND NOT ((Position LIKE '%Global%') OR (Position LIKE '%Interim Managing%'))
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: When Else the $string is blank. Im trying to use someone else's code to work and not fully understanding it.

Comment: Im struggling to create the WHERE clause from the above, i'm not sure how to create this.

Comment: Can anyone help?